# Possible spam detection by the system

Tags: bug, triage, spam, warning-message

While reviewing I came across this [triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19951995):

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

[image]

By the looks of it, question is no way near to spam. I don't understand why system detect possibility of spam in that question. Is there a specific pattern? Which thing should I look out for while creating a question?

Comment: Maybe there's been spam for services that provide fake 5 star app ratings?  You could look in [metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search) if you're especially curious.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom that system message isn't related to SmokeDetector/metasmoke at all; it's based on SE's own spam detection systems.

Comment: @angussidney I know the message isn't generated by SmokeDetector.  I hypothesized that there has recently been spam featuring some of the words in that post, hence triggering SE's own systems.  I mentioned metasmoke only as a way for the asker to look at recent spam posts if they are curious.

Comment: I'm... pretty sure that only shows up if someone has actually already flagged as spam.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say could be the combination of "five star rating" and so many instances of the word "hotel"? That probably bears a similarity to the sorts of verbiage that appears in many spam posts.